# Display time stamp in dd/mm/yyyy_hh:mm:ss:ms in Unix or Linux

Tags: date, timestamps

I need to display date and time in desired format in Unix/ Linux. My desired format is:
dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss:ms in Unix or Linux. I got close using the following command:

```
echo $(date +%x_%r)
```

This returns:

```
08/20/2012_02:26:14 PM
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is there any reason you are using `echo`? It seems redundant, you can just use `date` directly

Comment: I plan to stored the current time in a parameter and use it as part of a output file name.

Comment: Why not use a ISO formatted date string? Those / is no good in filenames... (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)

Comment: See this link: https://ccollins.wordpress.com/2009/01/06/how-to-change-date-formats-on-ubuntu/.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
date +%x_%H:%M:%S:%N
```

if you need to print only two first nums as ms:

```
date +%x_%H:%M:%S:%N | sed 's/\(:[0-9][0-9]\)[0-9]*$/\1/'
```

to store it in the var:

```
VAR=$(date +%x_%H:%M:%S:%N | sed 's/\(:[0-9][0-9]\)[0-9]*$/\1/')
```

Comment: This is Linux-specific; it doesn't work on OS X or *BSD.

Comment: Note %x returns the locale's date representation. So it can change based on the current locale. If you want that specific date format you are probably better off explicitly providing it (as other answers also show below) `date +'%d/%m/%Y_%H:%M:%S:%N`.

Answer (score 35):

If you want milliseconds instead of nanoseconds precision, you might use `%3N` instead of `%N`:

```
$ date +'%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S:%3N'
12/04/2014 18:36:20:659
```

or with your desired use of `$(…)`:

```
$ echo "$(date +'%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S:%3N')"
12/04/2014 18:36:20:659
```

But be aware, that `%N` may not implemented depending on your target system or bash version.
Tested on an embedded system »GNU bash, version 4.2.37(2)-release (arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabi)« there was no `%N` (neither  `%3N`):

```
date +"%F %T,%N"
2014-01-08 16:44:47,%N
```

Comment: Looks that neither FreeBsd nor Mac Osx supports `%N` or `%3N`.

Comment: I added `echo "$(date +'%F %H:%M:%S:%3N') Failed" >> logfile.txt`, but it wrote `file.file 08:21:02OURCE:184 Failed` to the logfile. What did I do wrong?

Comment: On macOS there's `gdate` in Homebrew https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/135749/181223

Answer (score 5):

[man date](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?date)

```
date +"%d/%m/%Y_%H:%M:%S:%N"
```

More useful reading:
[How to format date for display or to use in a shell script](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-formatting-dates-for-display/)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

`date +'%d/%m/%Y_%H:%M:%S:%N'`

Used `%N` for nanoseconds (000000000..999999999) since I did not find milliseconds right now

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
echo `date +"%Y_%m_%d %H:%M:%S,"``date +%N/1000000|bc -l|grep -Eo "^([0-9]{0,3})"`
```

For some reason '`' is omitted, so put it after the echo and at the end, or simply:

```
date +"[%Y_%m_%d %H:%M:%S,%3N]"
```