# Formatting current time

Tags: linux, timestamps, time

I would like to get time in below format

```
2020-10-12 10:41:42,526
```

How can it be done. I tried this but looks not correct

```
date +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S,%N"
```

Comment: Use `date +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S,%3N"` (I am sure this is a meme, not just duplicate)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Display time stamp in dd/mm/yyyy\_hh:mm:ss:ms in Unix or Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/45926/display-time-stamp-in-dd-mm-yyyy-hhmmssms-in-unix-or-linux)

Answer (score 1):

If the only issue is `%N` showing 9 digits instead of 3, you can fix it with prefixing it with number of digits to display `%3N`

```
$ date +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S,%3N"
2020-10-12 09:52:19,931
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that `%N` is a GNU `date` extension which give the `N`anoseconds part of the current time (0-padded to 9 digits). To get milliseconds instead, you could do:

```
date '+%F %T,%3N'
```

If that's a zsh script you're writing, you could do it portably with its `strftime` builtin instead:

```
zmodload zsh/datetime
strftime '%F %T,%3.'
```

Short for:

```
zmodload zsh/datetime
strftime '%F %T,%3.' $epochtime
```

Or for the radix character to be that of the user (assuming that's not `%` but I don't know of any locale where the radix character is `%`):

```
zmodload zsh/datetime
zmodload zsh/langinfo
strftime "%F %T${langinfo[RADIXCHAR]}%3."
```

If that's a ksh93 script, you can do it instead with its `printf` builtin:

```
printf '%(%F %T,%3N)T\n'
```

Short for:

```
printf '%(%F %T,%3N)T\n' now
```

Or with the user's radix char (again, assuming it's not `%`):

```
radixchar=$((1e-1))
radixchar=${radixchar//[0123456789]}
printf "%(%F %T${radixchar}%3N)T\n"
```